# Invoke oData expand from Controller

Tags: javascript, sapui5, netweaver

I want to invoke the following oData URL from the SAPUI5 controller.

```
/EmpSet('453233')/?$expand=EmpDetails
```

I am aware of oData model concepts and how to invoke normal read using oData model. However, I am struggling to invoke the above URL with the value 4533233.

As far as I understood, I can invoke it as follows:

```
oModel1.read( "/EmpSet('453233')", {

urlParameters: {"$expand": "EmpDetails"},

success: jQuery.proxy(this._fGetSuccess, this), error: 
jQuery.proxy(this._fGetError, this) });
```

However, the call goes for a toss and never hits the _fGetSuccess or _fGetError methods.

Can someone please guide me how to invoke the above URL from SAP UI5 controller

Regards,

Faddy

Comment: The issue [was a typo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48167580/5846045). This question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code looks flawless and the invocation goes for a toss, I think the issue is with _fGetSuccess and __fGetError methods. Can you check whether those methods are declared without any typos in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Issue was with the success method call back where there was a typo in callback method name.

Answer (score 0):

your are almost there. the following changes worked for me.

```
urlParameters: {
                $expand: "EmpDetails"
                }
```

example:

```
oModel1.read( "/EmpSet('453233')", {
                    urlParameters: {
                        $expand: "EmpDetails"
                    },
                    success: function(oData, response) {
                        var data = oData.results;
                        console.log(data);

                    }
                });
```

have fun.